# Grub: boot failed!

Tags: windows-7, grub

I installed a PCI [Magic Card](http://www.rogev.com/) on my system. It installs grub bootloader (I presume). When it tries to boot I get the following:

> Boot failed! Press any key to enter command line.

I'm using Windows 7. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: "It installs grub bootloader (I presume)."
Are you sure about this? The description on the manufacturer does not say anything about this.

Comment: @Michael It's definitely grub.

Comment: Which installation option did you choose? Did you set the card as your first boot device in BIOS?

Comment: Try to enter that command line and issue those commands: `root (0,0)` (or in Grub2: `set root=(hd0,1)`), `chainloader +1`, `boot`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/):
You can get it in 2 ways, on a live CD and on Ubuntu and probably some other Linux distros:

1st option:

[get a CD including Boot-Repair here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

boot the CD and choose recommended repair

2nd option:

[Download Ubuntu Live CD here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it on CD, or USB

boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.

choose "Try Ubuntu"

connect internet

open a new Terminal, then type:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

Press Enter and then type:

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

Press Enter

type `boot-repair` into Terminal and choose Recommended repair

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If that doesn't work, you might want to re-install Windows.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to preserve grub, get a linux live cd (preferably Ubuntu) and follow the instructions here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/

Comment: It seems to me that Grub is fine, but Windows is out.